# iOS and Android apps show up as Opted out after contact key registration

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, sfdcmobilesdk-android

1. Install the app (our app is has delayed regitration true)
2. Login to the app
3. Upon successful registration when contact key is created,
   the default status of the contact/device is "Not Opted In" and
   Opt-Out Source is "User Disabled Push".
4. When this user later manually toggles ON the notification, the contact/Device Id status does get updated to "Opted In"

**Expected:** I was hoping that when the new contact/device Id is created - the default state would be Optin Pending becuase the user is truly in a NotDetermined state

[image]